# Audio captcha not working on IE - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, captcha, recaptcha

I have a captcha webservice that returns audio but as doesn't play on IE. I suspect that's because if I hit the webservice on my IE browser directly, it prompts me to open or save while for my firefox it automatically loads and plays the audio captcha.

Is there any way I can load the audio automatically on the browser before play it for the user? This is what I have tried inside my js file but no luck :(

```
$scope.audio = document.createElement('audio');
$scope.audio.src="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/.../getSound"; //webservice call
$scope.audio.load();
$scope.audio.play();
```

[image: Detailed View]
[image: Summary View]

Comment: I don't remember there being a `load()` function on the audio element. Try removing `$scope.audio.load()`. `.play()` implies loading it anyway ;)

Comment: I've tried that but no luck. Pls see the attachments which makes it clear that IE expects me to save the audio file before it can be played.

Comment: "IE9 compat view" probably has something to do with it. Try using the correct document mode (you may be missing a `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start of your document)

Comment: Thanks ! ok, I have done some google and it seems .wav file plays under <bgsound> for IE but the issue now is to play <bgsound>requires src i.e the url of webservice which means it has to be a GET call. I am not sure if it is safe to expose captcha audio to users who could directly see it in firebug and hit it as many time as he likes :(

Comment: Any captcha would be visible in Firebug, no matter what. It's browser-side, therefore untrustable.

Comment: It might be visible even for POST but a user can't hit it but copy pasting the urls in browser and gets "METHOD NOT ALLOWED" error. Is there a way to restrict hits from outside application for GET as well?